# How do I pass an array of strings to C# web api from AngularJS?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

**data.js**

My method call:

```
var dateCollection = ["2014-12-12,"2013-12-12"];
getCompanyData(1,dateCollection);
```

---

```
var getCompanyData = function (Id, stmtDate)
        {
            var promise = $http.get(baseUrl() + "api/Search/CompanyData/" + Id + "/" + stmtDate)
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                    return data;
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    return data;
                });

            return promise;

        }
```

**SearchController.cs**

```
[ActionName("CompanyData")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCompanyData(string Id , string[] stmtDate)
{
}
```

I need to send array of `stmtDate` (which contains strings) to a `GetCompanyData` web API controller.

My `WebApiConfig.cs` has following route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ApiByMultiParams",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{Id}/{stmtDate}"
            );
```

The problem, is while trying to pass an array of data, when it hits the web API controller method: `GetCompanyData`, `stmtDate` doesn't receive the array and it is coming up as `null`. Also iI would appreciate any suggestions on how to convert a datetime which is in the format: `2014-12-12 00:00:00 to 2014-12-12` (in AngularJS).

Answer (score 1):

you are trying add array at end of url string. Send date as parametr

```
var getCompanyData = function (Id, stmtDate) {
    var promise = $http.get(baseUrl() + "api/Search/CompanyData/" + Id, {
            params: {
                date: stmtDate
            }
        }
    ).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            return data;
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            return data;
        });

    return promise;

}
```

Comment: i tried this but i got 404 error.should i modify webapiconfig.cs accordingly ,if i want to give this way?

Comment: how would it take my second parameter stmtDate if i give only Id in the webapiconfig?